# Optaplanner List Planning variable

Tags: java, drools, scheduling, optaplanner, resource-scheduling

Downloaded OptaPlanner examples, testing them. In the Meeting Scheduling example provided, a single planning variable is returned in the solved solution. for example, for a meeting scheduling, one Room is returned. I am planning to allocate multiple rooms for a single meeting schedule if the locations are different (assuming VC enabled for remote rooms). Current Meeting Scheduling example does not show this. Do I need to change the planning variable room to a List?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: Modified my question now. Apologies as I asked this question in a hurry. my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Planning variables can take on a range of values, as specified by `ValueRangeProviderRefs`. This is *always* a `Collections` object.

Check the `@PlanningSolution` class. There should be a annotation there: `@ValueRangeProvider(id="...")`, that returns a `List` comprised of just 1 single room. Modify this to return a list of rooms. You'll probably also need to adjust the scoring mechanism to account for multiple rooms.

Comment: Thanks Raymond for reply. When you are saying Modify this to return a list of rooms. you mean modifying below code?
 @ValueRangeProvider(id = "roomRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<Room> getRoomList() {
        return roomList;
    }

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? I am like stuck at the moment. I need your help in this